# Set range of markers in MapBox or Route-me

Tags: ios, objective-c, route-me, mapbox

I'm using **MapBox** to display an offline map that covers just a small portion of Earth and I want to show markers that have coordinates ranging from lng: **14.0 - 15.0** and lat: **54.0 - 55.0**.

The problem is that **MapBox/Route-Me** thinks that my map bounds are **-180 - 180** and **-85 - 85**. I can set `bounds` propery in `.mbtiles` but it doesn't help me because then it shows just a small portion of my map. I think I need to tell **MapBox** that my map is just **14.0 - 15.0** and lat: **54.0 - 55.0** and not whole world.

Answer (score 1):

You want this API to constrain the map:

http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/#//api/name/setConstraintsSouthWest:northEast:

Comment: Unfortunately this doens't help me. I does exactly the same thing as setting `bounds` in `.mbtiles`. It still thinks that my map's range is -180 - 180 and -85 - 85.
I'm trying to tell MapBox that my entire `.mbtiles` map covers only a small area of Earth (14.0 - 15.0 and lat: 54.0 - 55.0).

Comment: Did you try that API? It will constrain the map view itself, regardless of your MBTiles or any other tile source.